# Django - adding gamification features

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, separation-of-concerns

I have a [medium size Django REST app](https://github.com/samul-1/sai_evo_backend) that I'm looking to add gamification features to.

The application in question is a school webapp where students can create mockup quizzes, participate in exams that teachers publish, and write didactical content that gets voted by other students and teachers.

I want to add some gamification features to make the app more interesting and to incentivize participation and usage of the various features: for example, each student will have a personal "reputation" score, and gain points upon completing certain actions--a student may gain points when completing a quiz with a high score, when submitting some content, or when receiving upvotes to such content.

The tricky part is I want to be able to have this logic be as separate as possible from the existing codebase, for various reasons: separation of concerns, ability to plug the engine in/out if needed, ability to easily deactivate features for certain groups of users, etc.

What I'm looking for here is some software engineering advice that's also Django-specific. Here's a high level description of what I'm thinking of doing--I'd like some advice on the approach.

- create a new `gamification` app. Here I will have models that describe a change in reputation for a user and possibly other related events. The app should also send notifications when gamification-related events occur
- from the `gamification` app, expose a callback-based interface, which the other primary app can call into to dispatch events
- use the [django-lifecycle](https://github.com/rsinger86/django-lifecycle) package to call the callbacks from `gamification` when triggers occur.

This way, my existing models would only get touched to register the triggers from django-lifecycle (similar to signals). For example, let's say I want to give students points when they turn in an assignment. Let's say I have an `AssignmentSubmission` model to handle assignment submissions. With the added lifecycle hook, it'd look like this:

```
class AssignmentSubmission(models.Model):
    NOT_TURNED_IN = 0
    TURNED_IN = 1
    STATES = ((NOT_TURNED_IN, 'NOT_TURNED_IN'), (TURNED_IN, 'TURNED_IN'))

    user = models.ForeignKey(user)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(assignment)
    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATES, default=NOT_TURNED_IN)

    @hook(AFTER_UPDATE, when="state", was=NOT_TURNED_IN, is_now=TURNED_IN)
     def on_turn_in(self):
        get_gamification_interface().on_assignment_turn_in(self.user)
```

The `on_assignment_turn_in` method might look something like:

```
def on_assignment_turn_in(user):
    ReputationIncrease.objects.create(user, points=50)
    notifications.notify(user, "You gained 50 points")
```

This is pretty much just a sketch to give an idea.

I am unsure how `get_gamification_interface()` would work. Should it return a singleton? Maybe instantiate an object? Or return a class with static methods? I think it'd be best to have a getter like this as opposed to manually importing methods from the `gamification` app, but maybe it could also create too much overhead.

What's a good way to handle adding "pluggable" features to a project that are inherently entangled with existing models and business logic while also touching those as little as possible?

Comment: Did you take a look at how was made the django-gamification library : https://github.com/mattjegan/django-gamification ? It doesn't seem to be up to date but I feel like this is what you were thinking to implement. IMO, it's all about trying and see how it fits inside your project.

Comment: I did take a look at that. It *kinda* does some of the things that I want to do, as it defines achievables, badges, and points. But the main thing I'm missing is how to make my existing app hook into it without changing too much code, and how to make it generic enough to not have a single "gamification interface" (as that app calls it) per user and possibly allow points to be awarded in different "contexts", like happens here on SE where on different sites you have different reputation, badges, etc.

Comment: Alright, you have another alternative to trigger events in your gamification app without importing it through a `get_gamification_interface()`, it's by using Django Signals
 : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/ But it makes debugging harder so I'm unsure it's the best solution..

Comment: I don't understand why you're saying in your question : "I think it'd be best to have a getter like this as opposed to manually importing methods from the gamification app" ? What's the issue of importing it ?

Comment: I probably didn't phrase it well. If I have to import single functions, then my existing app becomes too tightly coupled with the gamification one, as it needs to know exactly that handlers are available. If I have a dispatcher, then my existing app could just send events as strings (like Django Channels does with consumers) without ever having to worry whether there is actually a piece of code to handle the event -- it'd be up to the gamification engine to just discard the event if it's not handled. My goal is facilitate futuer change as I'm not fully sure where I'm going with this app yet

Answer (score 3):

The foreign key approach is fine. You can easily chain and link queries using information from existing tables and you could even avoid touching the original code by importing your models to the new app. You can use Django signals in your new app and ditch the django-lifecycle extension to avoid adding lines to your core models. I used the following approach to keep track of modified records in a table; take a TrackedModel with fields field_one, field_two, field_n... which will be tracked by one of your new app's model, namely RecordTrackingModel:

```
from parent_app.models import TrackedModel # The model you want to track from a parent app.
from django.db.models.signals import post_save # I'm choosing post_save just to illustrate.
from django.dispatch import receiver
from datetime import datetime

class RecordTrackingModel(models.Model):
    record = models.ForeignKey(TrackedModel, verbose_name=("Tracked Model"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_one = models.TextField(verbose_name=("Tracked Field One"), null=True, blank=True) # Use same field type as original
    field_two = models.TextField(("Tracked Field Two"))
    field_n = ...
    notes = models.TextField(verbose_name=("notes"), null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=("Record creation date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=TrackedModel) # Here, listen for the save signal coming from a saved or updated TrackedModel record.
def modified_records(instance, **kwargs):
    record = instance
    tracked_field_one = instance.field_one
    tracked_field_two = instance.field_two
    tracked_field_n = another_function(instance.field_n) #an external function that could take a field content as input.
    ...
    note = 'Timestamp: ' + str(datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='seconds'))
    track_record = RecordTrackingModel.objects.create(record=record, field_one=tracked_field_one, field_two=tracked_field_two, field_n=tracked_field_n, ..., notes=note)
    return track_record
```

There's no need to add functions to your pre-existing models as the signal dispatcher triggers whenever a save or delete signal appears at TrackedModel. Then you could place "if" statements for wether or not to perform actions based on field values, i.e.: just pass if an AssignmentSubmission record has a "Not Turned In" status.

Check [Django signals reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/) for more information about when they trigger.

Additionally, I would suggest to change the "state" field to boolean type and rename it to something more explicit like "is_turned_in" for ease of use. It will simplify your forms and code. *Edit:* For more than 2 choices (non-boolean), I prefer using ForeignKey instead. It will let you modify choices over time easily from the admin site.

**Edit:**

Another approach could be mirroring the original models in your gamification app and call for a mirror record update when a save method is used in the original model.

*gamification_app/models.py:*

```
from parent_app.models import OriginalModel # The model you want to track from a parent app.
from django.db.models.signals import post_save # I'm choosing post_save just to illustrate.
from django.dispatch import receiver
from datetime import datetime

def gamification_function(input, parameters):
    output = *your gamification logic*
    return output
    

class MirrorModel(models.Model):
    original_model = (OriginalModel, verbose_name=("Original Model"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_one = ... #Same type as the original
    field_two = ...
    field_n = ...

    @hook(AFTER_UPDATE, when="field_n", was=OPTION_1, is_now=OPTION_2)
    def on_turn_in(self):
        gamification_function(self.field, self.other_field)

@receiver(post_save, sender=OriginalModel) # Here, listen for the save signal coming from the original app change record.
def mirror_model_update(instance, **kwargs):
    pk = instance.pk
    mirror_model = []
    if MirrorModel.objects.get(original_model.pk=pk).exists():
        mirror_model = MirrorModel.objects.get(original_model.pk=pk)
        mirror_model.field_one = instance.field_one # Map field values
        *other logic ...*
        mirror_model.save() # This should trigger your hook
    else:
        mirror_model = MirrorModel(original_model = instance, field_one = instance.field_one, ...)
        mirror_model.save() #This should trigger your hooks as well, but for a new record
```

This way you can decouple the gamification app and even choose not to keep a record of all or the same fields as the original model, but fields specific to your functionality needs.

Comment: Your solution with signals looks cleaner for sure. The reason I'm leaning towards using django-lifecycle is that I am interested in taking certain actions only if a field value goes from a specific value to another value. That package offers a facility to do it out of the box, whereas I would have to write some extra logic myself to track fields *old* values - not a big deal, but you know, it's always a good idea to see if you can spare youself writing some code. As for the state field, I simplified it here, but there's more than two possible values, that's why it's not a boolean

Comment: Oh, this is easily done, @SamueleB. you can use a `pre_save` signal, then `old_object = TrackedModel.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)`, and from there on it's pretty easy to compare `old_object` with `instance`, `if old_object.field != instance.field #the field changed` or, `if old_object.field == "this_is_the_specific_value_i_wanted":`

Comment: I see @SamueleB. so you need to make design decisions. `django-lifecycle` demands to be included in the model class, so in order to keep your original app clean, you could "mirror" the models and track the mirrored version instead using hooks. Then you could call a record modification function with signals, all from the new `gamification app`.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea was good.
In the *gamification* app add your views, protect it with LoginRequiredMixin, and extend it with a check if a related record in the **AssignmentSubmission** table exists and is turned on.

In this way you have a 100% separated gamification views, models, logic, ecc...

In the existing views you can add a link to a gamification view.